# Probability of picking 5 out of 10 football results

Tags: probability

Can anyone help me with this question that is puzzling me? I am after an explanation, not just the answer.

Lets say i predict 10 football results. Each result can be H, A or D. Home, Away or Draw, with equal chance 1/3.

What is the probability that i randomly pick exactly 5 out of 10 results correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Are each of the outcomes (H, A, and D) equally likely?

Comment: I guess we can assume each outcome (H,A,D) is equally likely. Don't tell me the answer is 50% ,surely not! :)

Comment: So you have a probability of $1/3$ of getting any particular game right, right?

Comment: Yes, 1/3 chance of picking a game.

Comment: Do you mean getting *exactly* 5 out of 10 result correct. Or (more likely) getting *5 or more* out of 10 results correct? Also, is it not constrained such that at least, say, 2 games are "home" or something like that?

Comment: I mean exactly 5 out of 10, with equal chance of H,A or D. I have a basic model which gave me 50% success and i want to know how much better/worse it is than chance.

Comment: It would be nice from you to edit your question and include all your additional info from your comments into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the probability of picking correctly is $1/3$ for each event, and the 10 football games are independent events, we can move forward. Assume that $C =$ total number of games picked correctly, $C$ follows the binomial distribution:

$$C \sim \mathrm{Binomial}(n = 10, p = 1/3),$$ and we want to find the probability that $C=5$.

I'm sure you're able to find the binomial probability mass function. Plugging in $n, p$ and $C$ into it, we derive that $$P(C=5) = {10\choose 5}\left({1 \over 3}\right)^5\left({2 \over 3}\right)^{10-5} = 0.1366.$$

So you have a 13.66% chance of picking exactly five games correctly.

Comment: In a comment to the question the OP asserts they achieve "50% success" with their guessing.  Maybe your answer ought to reflect that?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have only done limited testing of my model, but if it is predicting 50% of the results correctly 50% of the time, then this could be significant, if 13% is due to chance. I will do more testing to find out. Thanks again.

Comment: @brownie74 No problem! And if this answer was helpful to you, you may also accept it as the correct answer